# Add graphic representation for custom class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, graphics, controls

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to create a custom class that the user can add to the UI at run time. Basically, for simplicity, I have a class that I will call "Workstation" that has a method called Ping() and a property called IPAddress. When Ping() is called, if the IP address is pingable, I want my workstation "icon" to appear, and when it's not pingable, I want it to be invisible.

At runtime, the user would click "Add Workstation" (using the IP Address) which would create an instance of "Workstation" and he would be able to place the "workstation" icon in the grid. He would also be able to move it if needed.

What is the best way to do this ? I tried to inherit from the Image class (user control) but I'm trying to find a simpler way that wouldn't break the MVVM principles.

Comment: what about a DataTemplate ?

Comment: MethodMan, I like the name :) At the moment I have tried inheriting my "Workstation" class from the Controls.Image class, which works. The point of my question is to explore the possibilities so I can research each of them individually and decide on which works in my situation. I'm new to WPF and MVVM so I'm playing safe. So far, it looks like DataTemplate might be a good candidate as others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a DataTemplate

Xaml :

Define a namespace

```
  <UserControl xmlns:local="...your local namespace" >
      <UserControl.Resources>

         <DataTemplate x:Key="workStation" DataType="{x:Type local:WorkStation}">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding IPAddress}" />          
        </DataTemplate>
      </UserControl.Resources>

      <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentWorkStation}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource workStation}" />

   </UserControl>
```

cs :

```
  public class WorkStation 
  {
      public string IPAddress
      {
         get{ return "127.0.0.1";}
      }
  }
```

in your ViewModel :

```
  public WorkStation CurrentWorkStation
  {
      get{return new WorkStation();}
  }
```